# how to write an object to a tempfile in python

Tags: python

I want to write an object to a tempfile in python.

```
import tempfile

clip = Clip() // dynamic generated from ffmpeg
buffer = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size = 1024*1)
buffer.write(clip)
buffer.seek(0)
```

the content is an object and it is not a string type. How can it be implemented? Thanks

For example, this content is a movie clip. After creating a clip object, I want to upload it to a server. Then, delete it from memory.

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with object? How should it be represented as text?

Comment: use the pickle module to serialize it ... then save it...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Answer (score 2):

Serialize it, either as [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) or via [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Comment: does json reconstruct the original object? or is it just a dict?

Comment: JSON cannot serialize arbitrary objects either, without more detail as to what these objects *are*.

Comment: @Joran: `json` on its own only handles basic types, but it provides hooks for programmers to construct more complex objects on deserialize.

Comment: Use `pickle`.  It's effortless.

Comment: @japreiss Pickle is very intelligent and normally effortless, but it can get complicated for certain custom classes unless they implement __getstate__ and __setstate__